# Passing a JSON to PHP

Tags: php, javascript, json

I have a form with some check boxes and some select fields:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="service" value="1"> 
<select id="period1">
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
</select>   
<input type="checkbox" name="service" value="2">
<select id="period2">
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
</select>
```

I'm trying to pass the selected check box value and and a related select field value. 
For example: if the user checks the first check box the script should read "period1" value.

**The question is:** how to form the data using javascript and pass it to PHP using JSON. 
In PHP, I'd like to have kind of:

```
array => [0]
service["id"] => 1
service["period"] => 6
```

Thank you :)

Comment: do you want, the json sending to the server, or want the server convert? Becouse you can convert the $_POST with json_encode. But if you want json sending, you have to using javascript

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention: I'd like to convert the data using javascript

Answer (score 0):

use `json_encode()` to encode in json format and `json_decode()` to decode the data back in original form.

```
<?php
$arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);

echo json_encode($arr);
?>


<?php
$json = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';

var_dump(json_decode($json));
var_dump(json_decode($json, true));

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Convert form data to JavaScript object with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-js-object-with-jquery)

This link maybe help to you. And if you had json object, you can pass the server in post, like:

$.post("address", {json:jsonObj}, function(result){...});

I guess it is correct syntax, correct me if i mistake.